# prefix and post each element in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

Team,
`GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release`
I have this array and I want to prefix `-//` and postfix `...` to each element inside it.

I tried it like this for prefix.

```
bazel_ignore_paths=("${b[*]}")
PRE_POST_ARRAY=("-//${bazel_ignore_paths[@]/%/...}")
```

printf "new array to skip bazel on: %s\n\n" "${PRE_POST_ARRAY[*]}"

output: observe that only one path got changed with prefix and the second one with postfix. I want all to change with both pre and post.

```
new array to skip bazel on: 

-//src/services/access-management/ src/services/asset-manager/...
```

expected output

```
-//src/services/management/...  -//src/services/manager/...
```

Comment: `bazel_ignore_paths=("${b[*]}")` expands array `b` as one single word. It is not what you want. What you want is `bazel_ignore_paths=("${b[@]}")` that expands array `b` as as many words as there are elements in the array. Then try: `bazel_ignore_paths=("${b[@]/#/-//}")` followed by `bazel_ignore_paths=("${bazel_ignore_paths[@]/%/...}")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do both at the same time, have to go two times:

```
$ arr=(a b c)
$ echo ${arr[@]/%/_}
a_ b_ c_

$ echo ${arr[@]/#/_}
_a _b _c

$ arr=( "${arr[@]/#/_}" )
$ arr=( "${arr[@]/%/_}" )
$ echo ${arr[@]}
_a_ _b_ _c_
```

Comment: hmm not sure what is happening. same thing it is only adding to first and last path not to all. this is with your solution.     
`bazel_ignore_paths=( "${bazel_ignore_paths[@]/#/-//}" )`
`bazel_ignore_paths=( "${bazel_ignore_paths[@]/%/...}" )`

Comment: you I need to execute all the steps you laid out in your answer or just the last two before echo?

Comment: tried all. it does not. just sufixes to first element and then to last one.

Comment: @AhmFM Just the last two before `echo`. Make sure `bazel_ignore_paths` is actually an array, not just a single string with spaces in it. Use `declare -p bazel_ignore_paths` to see what it is.

Comment: you are right it was not array.

Comment: i converted it to array then it worked. `bazel_ignore_paths=($bazel_ignore_paths)`

Comment: @AhmFM Do not do this, it works by chance. Please read my comment below your question and use what I suggest.

Comment: Too late I pushed it to production. Lol. Let me revert but will test now. Thanks for carefulness.

Comment: @AhmFM It's extremely important to FULLY understand all the pros, cons, and caveats of any script you find online before using it as it's usually trivial to write a script that will produce the expected output from some specific set of input but much harder to not produce unexpected output and/or have other (sometimes disastrous) consequences given other input.

Comment: Even the script in this answer has caveats that can/will bite you given different input due to the quotes having been removed from the echo lines and even just the fact they're using echo instead of printf. As a starting point you should copy/paste any script you're considering using into http://shellcheck.net (as the [tag:bash] tag you used tells you to do) before using it. That wont find all potential problems but it'll at least catch the basic ones like missing quotes.

Answer (score 3):

In bash 5.2 you can do this in one pass like so:

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${a[@]/*/-\/\/&...}"
-//1... -//2... -//3...
```

Comment: any wasy for 4.3 bash?

Comment: Most probably because of `patsub_replacement` which is on by default even on shell script afaik.

Comment: @Jetchisel patsub_replacement is for backwards compatibility, & being replaced with the matched substring is the default behavior from bash 5.2 on and won't change

Comment: @oguz-ismail You're a lifesaver! I can't seem to find any examples of this in the documentation though. Apart from `patsub_replacement`, do you know the name of this particular operator?

Comment: @GrabbenD I don't. It's documented under *Pattern substitution*

Answer (score -2):

if you don't wanna fuzz too much with `bash` `regex`, a good ole `printf` can do (most) of the job

( *I'm on `zsh` ; haven't tested it on `bash`*)

> ```
> __=( $( jot -w 'src/0xB%c/tmp' - 33 126 | grep -E '0xB[0-9A-F]' ) )
> ```

---

> ```
> __=( $( printf './/%s...\n' "$__[@]" ) )
>
>         printf '%s ' $__[@] | gcat -n  # not sure if array variable
>                                        # needs to be safe quoted here or not
> ```

```
  1 .//src/0xB0/tmp... .//src/0xB1/tmp... .//src/0xB2/tmp...
    .//src/0xB3/tmp... .//src/0xB4/tmp... .//src/0xB5/tmp...
    .//src/0xB6/tmp... .//src/0xB7/tmp... .//src/0xB8/tmp... 
    .//src/0xB9/tmp... .//src/0xBA/tmp... .//src/0xBB/tmp... 
    .//src/0xBC/tmp... .//src/0xBD/tmp... .//src/0xBE/tmp... 
    .//src/0xBF/tmp...
```

Comment: I have no clue what you answered sorry.

Comment: @AhmFM : which part of the single `printf` statement confused you ?